# Can I arrive before my German National Visa D is valid (e.g 2 weeks)?

Tags: visas, germany, australian-citizens, schengen-visas

I am an Australian, and we can travel in the Schengen Area for 3 months in 6 month period using the Schengen Visa Waiver program.

Can I arrive in the Germany on the Schengen Visa Waiver program two weeks before my National D Visa is valid?

Comment: hey @vaughan how did this turn out? Did you end up going before your visa was valid and were the border guards confused? I'm planning to do the same but for Austria (visa-free entry before visa d is valid).

Comment: @Ozzy I think it would be fine. Just enter using waiver program. In the US I read a story of someone being detained and deported when trying to enter on a tourist visa whilst applying for a work visa - which is why I think I asked this question.